# Cluster labels become float

Tags: python

I tried to add the cluster labels to the map.

The array(the first pic) shows the labels were int, Why later df (second pic) the label become float 1.0?
and how to change the Cluster Labels column back to int,like 1, not 1.0? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9958

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used how='inner' from this discussion, and it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably if you're loading data into a dashboard, the dashboard columns take a certain type. Not enough info here to properly debug, but I'd wager that ClusterLabels has a default type of int when loaded into the dashboard